# Extract string after particular pattern

Tags: java, android, regex

I lost my head after trying to understand the way to extract the string after a particular pattern in one string.

the pattern is #|# and the string for example is:
Scirocco_#01_#|#Cp1freezer
I would like to find the pattern and extract the string after the end of pattern:
Cp1freezer

I have tried with regex expression ^(.*)#|#(.*)$ but I don't find the way out.

```
String input = "Scirocco_#01#|#Cp1";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^(.*)#|#(.*)$").matcher(input);
if(m.find()) {
  String first = m.group(1); // Scirocco_#01
  String second = m.group(2); // Cp1
}
```

Comment: Usw regex101 to debug such regexes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to escape the `|` to match it literally. Second, you don't need to capture what precedes `#|#` if you only wish to extract what follows the `#|#`, so can remove the beginning of your expression. The first capture group will contains the desired substring:

[`"#\\|#(.*)$"`](https://regex101.com/r/fH9cF6/1)

Demo: https://ideone.com/msXR3U

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the pipe '|'

Like this:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^(.*)#\\|#(.*)$").matcher(input);
```